# Making windows appear on Bottom

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter, wxpython

How can I make a window appear at the bottom of the window stack? Preferably with Tkinter (However, WXPython works too). I'd like it to appear below every other window. This is in Windows 7, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package can give you access to Windows Scripting functions.  For example, select a window by title and move it to the bottom of the Z order:

```
import win32ui, win32con as w

def MoveToBack(window_name):
    flags = w.SWP_NOSIZE | w.SWP_NOMOVE | w.SWP_NOACTIVATE | w.SWP_SHOWWINDOW | w.SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS 
    hwnd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    hwnd.SetWindowPos(w.HWND_BOTTOM, (0,0,0,0), flags)
```

This is obviously a Windows-only solution.